# How add some checks for list of API in filter

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, filter, python-requests

I have this filter and I need to add for REQUEST list API from some function (for example `check()` that have some logic) How can I change in this filter?
I was trying with:

```
requestMatchers(*REQUEST)
  .access(tokenProvider.handleTokenForWhitelist() == true)
```

but it doesn't work.

```
fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        return http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers(*AUTH_WHITELIST + REQUEST).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .and()
            .addFilterAfter(
                JWTFilter(tokenProvider, accountTokenRepository),
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java
            )
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationErrorHandler).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .build()
    }
```